# Sharepoint Redirects if not specifying /pages/default.aspx

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, url-rewriting, seo

Hope someone can help.

I have a Sharepoint web app which I've given a new URL (Host header). Now, whenever I browse to http://newurl, it does a redirect to http://oldurl and then to http://newurl/pages/default.aspx

If I however browse to http://newurl/pages/default.aspx, then no problems, no redirects.

Any idea what's causing this? Is this a AAM issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to change the IIS settings SharePoint thinks it control in IIS manager (at least not without telling sharepoint).

SharePoint notices that you access it through an unknown zone so it redirects you to the default zone which has the url http://oldurl

So please go into AAM and tell sharepoint what you did :-)

Comment: Thanks Per, this makes sense. My apologies Sharepoint :-)